# Manage sqlite in android system?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know how to manage sqlite database in android system.
When I use SQLiteDatabase to save data, where is it save in android system?

I want to know it because when I save data via sqlite, other developer can or not to open and change it?

Thanks.

Comment: As a file in the data folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saving in your mobile internal storage as a file of your database name:

directory is : (internal storage path)..../Android/data/packageName/database/

but the database file will not visible but you can write it to another path and then open with sqlite browser.

How to write the database into another file :

```
    private void write() throws IOException {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (sd.canWrite())
            {
                String currentDBPath = DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
                String backupDBPath= "QSDevice.db";

                File currentDB = new File(getDBPath(), currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        }

 private String getDBPath() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files", "databases") +
                    File.separator;
        } else {
            return getFilesDir().getPath() + getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you save via SQLite in android is saved in the data->data->(your package name)->database->(your database name) of your android device. Other apps and developers cannot access your database if you selected the mode to be PRIVATE. And you can access this database using the ANDROID DEVICE MANAGER which you can open from the Tools->Android->Android Device Manager. It will open an eclipse DDMS in your android Studio. You can​ open file explorer and go to the directory of your database and pull it from there

Comment: How can I access to data->data->... I can't access.

Comment: first you have to open the Android Device Manger (this will open eclipse perspective of DDMS in which you can access the files on your emulator). after that perspective opens, just click on the file explorer and select the Data folder

Comment: After you see this file in the file explorer of DDMS, you have to pull it using the button at the top right saying the same. And save it to any location you want